# Twig.js. Macro pasándole una variable (objeto) no definida da error

Tags: nodejs, twig

Estoy intentando hacer una macro para pequeñas comprobaciones de variables.

```
{% macro check(var) %}
  {% if var is not defined %}
    <p>error</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Si le paso un nombre de una supuesta variable funciona:

```
{{ check(foo) }}
```

Si le paso un "objeto" da error

```
{{ check(foo.bar) }}
```

Si por ejemplo foo existe pero bar no, entonces si funciona

```
{% set foo = { } %}
```

Si la comprobación la hago sin macro, siempre funciona.